# How can I place divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I was trying to displace 6 divs side by side using a display grid but they are getting displayed in rows. I had used display grid but it still didn't work, I also tried a few more ways which I searched on StackOverflow. Can you tell what I did wrong or suggest an alternative to this. The 2 divs are box1 and box2. Here is a reference picture

[![pic1][1]][1]

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navlist {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 477px;
  top: 45px;
  position: relative;
}

.bar {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 80px;
}

.link1 {
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px
}

.signin {
  background: blue;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 15%;
  top: 20px
}

.sign {
  top: 15%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none
}

.pic {
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%
}

.introbox {
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('wal.jpg');
  opacity: 0.75;
  left: 25%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px;
}

.new {
  font-size: 30px;
  left: 20%;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400
}

.box1 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
  display: grid;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600
}

.box2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 1%;
  display: grid;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.lnlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black
}

.lightnovel1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  background: red;
  left: 5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.ww {
  grid-row: 1/3
}
<div class="bar">
  <img src="background.png" class="pic">
  <nav>
    <ul class="navlist">
      <li><a href='#' class="link1">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class="link1">Browse</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class="link1">Tags</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class="link1">Filter</a></li>
      <li><a href='#' class="link1">Dev</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="signin"><a href="#" class='sign'>Sign In</a></div>
</div>
<div class="introbox">
  <h1>Read Light Novel & Web Novel Translations Online For FREE!</h1>
  <p2>Your fictional stories hub</p2>
  <br>
  <p3>Looking for a great place to read Light Novels? Light Novel Pub is a very special platform where you can read the translated versions of world famous Japanese, Chinese and Korean light novels in English. Every new chapters published by the author is
    updated instantly on the Light Novel Pub and notification service is provided to the readers.

  </p3>

  Start reading now to explore this mysterious fantasy world.
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="release">
  <div class="title1">
    <h3 class="new">New Ongoing Release</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="lightnovel1">
    <div class="ww" <div class="box1">
      <img src="martialart.jpg" class="pic2">
      <a href="#" class="lnlink">Martial Art System </a>
      <div class="rank">
        <p2> Rank 1
          <p2>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <img src="martialart.jpg" class="pic2">
        <a href="#" class="lnlink">Martial Art System </a>
        <div class="rank">
          <p2> Rank 1
            <p2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqMBa.png
```

Comment: Try display flex

Comment: it doesnt work for some reason. its still the same @Yarin Levi

Comment: I will try to fix that ..

Answer (score 1):

Change the grid-template-columns and use the repeat function depending on the number of columns you want to display.

```
.bar{
  height: 100px ;
  width: 100% ;
  justify-content: center ;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px ;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
}
```

or

```
.bar{
  height: 100px ;
  width: 100% ;
  justify-content: center ;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px ;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px repeat(4, auto) 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is containing a lot of small errors, that might be why you're experiencing weird results with your page. For example:

- `<div class="ww"` is missing a closing `>`
- `<p2> Rank 1 <p2>` starting two unknown p2 tags, that never closes

After fixing those issues, and adding `display: flex;` to `.ww`, your divs appear next to each other.

Try switching over to a code editor, that can easily visualize those errors for you, like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px ;
}

.navlist{
  list-style: none ;
  display: flex ;
  padding: 0px ;
  margin: 0px auto ;
  width: 477px ;
  top: 45px ;
  position: relative;
}

.bar{
  height: 100px ;
  width: 100% ;
  justify-content: center ;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px ;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto 80px;
}

.link1{
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none ;
  color: black ;
  font-size: 20px
}

.signin{
  background:blue ;
  height: 35px ;
  width: 100px ;
  left: 50px ;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center ;
  font-size: 18px ;
  border-radius: 15% ;
  top: 20px
  
}

.sign{
 top: 15% ;
 position: relative;
 color: white ;
 text-decoration: none
}

.pic{
  position: relative;
  left: -100px ;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 75%
}

.introbox{
  width: 700px ;
  height: 200px ;
  background-image: url('wal.jpg');
  opacity: 0.75 ;
  left: 25% ;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center ;
  top: 10px ;
  border-radius: 5px ;
  font-weight: 600 ;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px ;
}

.new{
  font-size: 30px ;
  left: 20% ;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400
}



.box1{
  height: 250px ;
  width: 200px ;
  background: green ;
  position: relative;
  top: 2% ;
  display: grid ;
  font-size: 20px ;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.box2{
  height: 250px ;
  width: 200px ;
  background: green ;
  position: relative;
  top: 1% ;
  display: grid ;
  font-size: 20px ;
  font-weight: 600 ;
}



.lnlink{
  text-decoration: none ;
  color: black
}



.lightnovel1{
  position: relative;
  height: 800px ;
  width: 800px ;
  background: red ;
  left: 5%  ;
  display: grid;
  grid-row:  1/3;
}

.ww{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="bar">
   <img src="background.png" class="pic">
   <nav>
     <ul class="navlist">
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Search</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Browse</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Tags</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Filter</a></li>
       <li><a href='#' class="link1">Dev</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="signin"><a href="#" class='sign'>Sign In</a></div>
 </div>
 <div class="introbox">
<h1>Read Light Novel & Web Novel Translations Online For FREE!</h1>
<p2>Your fictional stories hub</p2>
<br>
<p3>Looking for a great place to read Light Novels?

Light Novel Pub is a very special platform where you can read the translated versions of world famous Japanese, Chinese and Korean light novels in English. Every new chapters published by the author is updated instantly on the Light Novel Pub and notification service is provided to the readers.

</p3>

Start reading now to explore this mysterious fantasy world.
 </div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="release">
  <div class="title1">
    <h3 class="new">New Ongoing Release</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="lightnovel1">
    <div class="ww">
      <div class="box1">
        <img src="martialart.jpg" class="pic2">
        <a href="#" class="lnlink">Martial Art System </a>
        <p> Rank 1 </p>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <img src="martialart.jpg" class="pic2">
        <a href="#" class="lnlink">Martial Art System </a>
       <p> Rank 1 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```